# Not seeing Django logs on Heroku

Tags: logging, python, django, heroku

I'm not seeing log entries (at a level of `INFO`) made by Django in my Heroku logs.

This is my configuration:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
        },
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
        'not_development_filter': {
            '()': NotDevelopmentFilter,
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console':{
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'null': {
            'class': 'django.utils.log.NullHandler',
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['not_development_filter'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'include_html': True,
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins', 'console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'py.warnings': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
        },
    }
}
```

I'd like to see the log entries in the Heroku interface. Any idea why I'm not seeing them there?

Comment: Do you see anything if you just `print` something to `stdout`?

Comment: It's been two years ;)

Comment: I found it is still unanswered. =)

Comment: @RamRachum If it's solved, write an answer, or close it somehow - otherwise it'll continue to pop up on people's radar.

Answer (score 2):

In the [python-getting-started](https://github.com/heroku/python-getting-started) app, for a log that isn't tagged `django`, `ERROR` level logs show up in `heroku` logs, but `INFO` logs don't.

To make it work for logs that aren't tagged `django`, it needs a config like the following (similar to yours):

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
    },
}
```

So if you adjust your configuration to otherwise be like python-getting-started, including the Procfile, it should hopefully work.

Here's a log that isn't tagged django, that I added to `views/hello.py`:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    logger.error('testing logging!')
    logger.info('testing info logging')
    logger.debug('testing debug logging')

    # return HttpResponse('Hello from Python!')
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

When I first tried it, only the error log showed up. When I added the logging config in the code snippet above the previous one, the info and the error logs showed up. This is all with `DEBUG = False` (changed from the code in the repo, which has `DEBUG = True`).

It probably is better to, rather than have the empty string key, so everything is logged, to have a more specific `loggers` entries than just the empty string (`''`).

Finally, in your log file, there's  a case where INFO logs won't appear on the console, or Heroku logs: If it's an INFO log to `django.request`, with your config it will only go to `'mail_admins'` because `propagate` is `False`. I think that in this case, it would make more sense for `propagate` to be set to `True`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same thing that `INFO` level does not show up but in my case (and as @Benjamin Atkin reports as well) `ERROR` did.

The core problem seems to be that this call:

```
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

removes whatever custom loggers you might have setup in your `LOGGING` dict.

The solution is to add this to the call so that it does not mess with your logging setup:

```
django_heroku.settings(locals(), logging=False)
```

Or better yet don't use it at all, since this package is deprecated anyway.

Comment: I found `logging=False` useful. I don't know about "don't use it at all", but your mileage may vary.